Where to change the text color for tabs having modified files in PhpStorm?
In PhpStorm having the default Dark Theme, modified files are shown with a light blue color in the tabs' row.
I am customizing the color scheme via
Setting > Editor > Color Scheme > General
so that I can get more contrast, e.g.: have a strong highlight on the Selected Tab.
While I can change the background color of the Selected Tab, and have once the file is modified, the blue text color is used.
I assume the blue color stems from something indicating: Changed / Modified files.
Yet I cannot find where it comes from.


From what I see, that's a VCS status colors -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/project-tool-window.html#file_status_highlight

@LazyOne I went through the settings at Editor > Color Schemes > VCS, yet there is no clear way to change the text color. Editor Gutter and VCS annotation all only have background colors set, and while some background colors appear to be in that blue, changes them does not have any effect on the tab row.

Ah, I got confused by your comment. The link points to: File status highlights.

Yes, the settings path is Settings/Preferences | Version Control | File Status Colors

As pointed out by Lazy One in the comments, the colors can be changed via File status highlights at:
Version Control | File Status Colors


Related background color under the tab: File > Settings > Editor > Color Scheme > General > Tabs > Underline
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360008005220/comments/360001556900
